# Performance issue with JPA dashboards

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a production server that is experiencing severe performance issues because  need to display annual sales data in a graphical report.

I didn't find any way to obtain all this data, other than through a JPA query with the year filter. However, this results in a massive volume of data, causing the application to be very slow.

How could I improve the performance of this type of generalist query?

Comment: Don't write a JPA query, write a dedicated SQL query that retrieves what you need (or write the proper JPA query which does that instead of navigating all objects and relations to get a few properties).

Comment: @M.Deinum can you give to me some example(s) please?

Comment: A sample of what? I Don't know your model so I don't know what to write as a query. I assume you know how to write a proper JPQL or SQL query for the data you need. If you are quering some toplevel JPA entity then iterate over it gettting properties and properties of nested structures you are simply doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying a JPA entity field using a JPA query, you need to ensure that the field you are looking up in the database has an appropriate B-tree index. In your case, create an index on the 'year' column; it should significantly improve the performance. Also, ensure that you really need all the data you fetch from the database.